# Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 from usb pendrive

Tags: system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 in my laptop. It's an i3 processor with Windows 7 - 64 bit already installed. Please guide me as to what to do...

Comment: What about this ? http://i.stack.imgur.com/zTEOW.png

Comment: Make sure you have enough space on the hard drive,  read everything that appears on the screen,  make sure you go to "try ubuntu" option and just see if everything works ( sound,  wifi, wired Internet,  graphics ). I rushed into my first installation and was lucky that with 18 gb of space everything worked and without bugs.  But now I know it was kinda hasty. Spend extra time preparing , it's worth it

Comment: I don't claim to be expert with windows 7, but I will say this, historically, or at least not since Windows 98, it has not been possible to boot more than one computer to windows 7, so if you do that you must only boot one computer to windows 7, and only boot to Ubuntu on all other computers that pendrive is booted on.  Feel free to hit me up for tips on higher performance pendrive.  I've been doing this a few years and know what is fast and where the deals are.

Comment: whoopsy,  Misunderstood your request.  Please disregard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: This has too many duplicates and i suggest you show some effort with finding answers. There's this website that I love which can help you, it's called google.com

Answer (score 0):

Just download the newest image from [Ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Use [LiLi](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download) to create a bootable USB drive or burn the image to a disc.
Boot from the created medium and follow the instructions. The installer will ask you if you want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, just use this option.

Comment: I prefer "Linux 1 2 3" > http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Answer (score 0):

I would better suggest, use Universal USB Installer (UUI). Download it from [HERE](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

If you have an .iso file of ubuntu, go with the procedure described in the linked page. 
Reboot system, boot from pen drive and there is your ubuntu live from the disk. 
Now click on the **install** and choose **along with windows**. This will install the Ubuntu along with the windows you are using.